# Conversational English corpus for download

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, corpora

I have a project which requires a corpus of conversational English in plain text (although I can perform some processing as needed). Since I am a student, I need to find a corpus that is free and downloadable. I would appreciate it if someone could provide suggestions for such corpora.

Comment: [**MICASE**](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/c/corpus/corpus?c=micase;page=simple) might meet your needs. Or it might not.

Comment: Do you care for answers to your question? Why don't you do anything (accept, vote, comment)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English text corpus for download](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/english-text-corpus-for-download)

Comment: @zixuan I think "text" and "conversational" corpora are two different enough things to deserve different questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many spoken English corpora available. But generally, you need to ask more questions than 'plain text' before you find the right one. Length, level of annotation, format of annotation, type of conversation, genre/register, dialect, natural vs. elicited, etc. Those will all depend on the type of research questions you want to answer.

If you just want any one corpus you could try:

- Santa Barbara Corpus of Spoken American English: http://www.linguistics.ucsb.edu/research/santa-barbara-corpus#Contents
- CHILDES collection of corpora (most is conversation) - http://childes.psy.cmu.edu/
- BASE - British Academic Spoken English http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/soc/al/research/collect/base/

There are others (like the [Switchboard corpus](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/language-resources/data/obtaining)) which you can download for a fee or buy on CD (like the [Edinburgh Map Task corpus](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/maptask/)).

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find the *Saarbrücken Corpus of Spoken English (SCoSE)*:

http://www.uni-saarland.de/lehrstuhl/engling/scose.html

Comment: Those files encode tone, power and pauses; but lack tagging of parts-of-speech or lemmas.

Comment: There are decent tools for those task freely available, so you can add these annotation automatically.

Comment: I think the characters added to encode sonic features would choke any POS tagger.  Are there plain text versions of the SCoSE files?

Answer (score 1):

I had success with the conversation transcripts provided by [UNC Charlotte](https://search.uncc.edu/?q=conversation%20site%3Ansv.uncc.edu).